# Linkedin login page does not render properly

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

We are having problems with connecting to linkedin in our iOS apps. 
Connect and cancel buttons does not appear properly. We also checked version that is currently on app store, it also does not work(worked previously).
We are using newest version of linkedin framework.

For connecting we use code:

```
let permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION]
    LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: {
        returnState in
        //handle success
    }) { error in
        //handle error
    }
```

Is it a problem with linkedin iOS app?

[image: layout problem]